# How can we connect with another applications to sharepoint list and read it's items?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-integration, integration

Can we connect to SharePoint list from another applications and read it's info items **by web service?** or another way ...?

In our windows based application or web based application we want to show items in SharePoint lists.

Goals:

- retrieve information in another application)
- access to SharePoint in another enterprise software
- Integrate Applications

**/EDIT**

we also have 2007 and 2010 version of sharepoint .

Comment: what version of sharepoint do you use?

Comment: @TZHX thanks for your attention. we also have 2007 and 2010 version of SharePoint .

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint exposes an API, and you can find there a service for accessing lists and the list items: ListData.svc a wcf service that follows REST protocol. Here's a link with a tutorial on how to do it: http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/07/09/get-list-items-in-sharepoint-2010/

If you are having trouble with the CAML query, use the CAML query builder from: http://spcamlqueryhelper.codeplex.com/

Hope it helps.